# Find first list item with data attribute greater than a date value

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have a list of items that have a date data attribue in the format "yy/mm/dd 00:00"

I'm going to add a list item to that list but I need to find its correct place in line. So if I have an item with the date value "2012/04/22 21:30", then I need to find the first list item with a date value greater than that and then prepend the list item before it.

So I'll have my list items

```
<li data-date="2010/04/05 20:40"></li>
<li data-date="2011/06/05 21:40"></li>
<li data-date="2012/08/05 22:40"></li>
<li data-date="2013/10/05"></li>
```

And then a new dymanic list item I need to insert into the list above

```
<li data-date="2012/04/22 21:30"></li>
```

How do I solve this with Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the attribute `data-date` of new `li` to be inserted  with the list items already present in DOM.

```js
$(function() {
  var c = 0;
  var a = '<li data-date="2011/06/05 21:40">2011/06/05 21:40</li>';
  var aa = Date.parse($(a).attr('data-date'));
  $('li').each(function(i, v) {
    var aaa = ($(v).attr('data-date'));
    var b = Date.parse(aaa);
    if (b > aa) {
      $(a).insertBefore(v);
      c = 1;
      return false;
    }
  })
  if (!c) {
    $('ul').append(a);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-date="2010/04/05 20:40">2010/04/05 20:40</li>
  <li data-date="2012/08/05 22:40">2012/08/05 22:40</li>
  <li data-date="2013/10/05 22:40">2013/10/05 22:40</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should approach the requirement this way,

1. Call all the nodes, fetch their values and store in an array. Then
   convert all date-time values to seconds.
2. Re-arrange them in ASC/DESC order as per your requirement.
3. Convert the values to the original format again, encapsulate the
   value with `<li></li>` tag and other attributes.
4. Replace newly generated HTML with the older one.

I'm not sure if it's the best approach to do this, but this is a working solution.